# How to make an autocomplete field in Symfony3?

Tags: php, jquery, symfony, autocomplete

I want to do an autocomplete to use in my TextType form.

Im using Symfony 3.

What bundle do i need to use?

I tryed:

- ShtumiUsefulBundle (requires Symfony2)
- samson/autocomplete-bundle (requires Symfony2)
- IoFormBundle (deprecated)
- PUGXAutocompleterBundle (The typical use case is when you get a Many-to-One relation)

**Update**

Im trying **tetranz/select2entity-bundle**

In my Controller:

```
/**
 * Lists all region entities.
 *
 * @Route("/candidat/listeRegion", name="get_liste_region")
 * @Method("GET")
 */
public function getListeRegionAction()
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $regions = $em->getRepository('GECandidatBundle:Region')->findAll();

    $list_region = array();
    foreach ($regions as $region){
        $obj['id'] = $region->getId();
        $obj['text'] = $region->getNom();
        array_push($list_region,$obj);
    }
    return new JsonResponse($list_region);
}
```

The JsonResponse return an array of objects:

> [{"id":1,"text":"region1"},{"id":2,"text":"region2"},{"id":3,"text":"region3"}]

In my buildForm:

```
$builder
        ->add('lieuxTravailSouhaites', Select2EntityType::class, [
            'label' => 'Lieux travail souhaites *',
            'label_attr' => [
                "class" => "smaller lighter blue",
                "style" => "font-size: 21px;",
            ],

            'multiple' => true,
            'remote_route' => 'get_liste_region',
            'class' => 'GECandidatBundle:Region',
            'primary_key' => 'id',
            'text_property' => 'name',
            'minimum_input_length' => 2,
            'page_limit' => 10,
            'allow_clear' => true,
            'delay' => 250,
            'cache' => true,
            'cache_timeout' => 60000, // if 'cache' is true
            'language' => 'fr',
            'placeholder' => 'Sélectionnez un lieu',
            // 'object_manager' => $objectManager, // inject a custom object / entity manager
        ])
```

when I type two letters it does not display the exact words. even if I write the full word it does not select it,it does not work properly.

I checked my jquery it's imported:

```
<script src="{{ asset('assets/vendor/jquery/jquery-3.2.1.min.js') }}"></script>
```

In the browser console im getting this error:

> spinners.js:21 Uncaught TypeError: $(...).chosen is not a function
>       at HTMLDocument. (spinners.js:21)
>       at j (jquery.min.js:2)
>       at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.min.js:2)
>       at Function.ready (jquery.min.js:2)
>       at HTMLDocument.J (jquery.min.js:2)

What do I have to do?

Comment: You can do some classic ajax application. If you do so then you could use the FOSJsroutingBundle to expose your routes to your javascript code.

Comment: Check out the tetranz bundle https://github.com/tetranz/select2entity-bundle it integrate easily.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, im trying the 'tetranz Bundle' and i have problem with 'remote_route' option i creater a action method in my Controller wich return JsonResponse but it did not work.